# MongoDB agregation and comparing

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I need to write mongodb query that will agregate items by quantinty (orders collestion). After agregation, or with agregation, it should identify items that can't be supplied in stock collection, and return name of the person who made this order

code of orders insert

```
db.orders.insertMany([
{client:  {firstName: "John",lastName: "Smith" },orderedItems: [{ name: "itemA", qty: 5},{ name: "itemS", qty: 3}]},
{client:  {firstName: "Jan",lastName: "Nowak" },orderedItems: [{ name: "itemA", qty: 56},{ name: "itemS", qty: 53}]},
{client:  {firstName: "Klara",lastName: "Bolączka" },orderedItems: [{ name: "itemA", qty: 35},{ name: "itemS", qty: 23}]},
{client:  {firstName: "Brajan",lastName: "Kowalski" },orderedItems: [{ name: "itemA", qty: 95},{ name: "itemS", qty: 13}]}
]);
```

code of stocks insert

```
db.stock.insertMany([
{ item: "itemA", qty: 40},
{ item: "itemS", qty: 113}  
]);
```

Right now i got some mongoDB code, that just agregates orders

```
db.orders.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$orderedItems"},
{$group: { _id: "$orderedItems.name", total:{$sum: "$orderedItems.qty"}}}
]);
```

I tried to use lookup, but probably I'm doing something wrong.

Could I get some sugestions, please?

Comment: I'd say the first thing you are doing wrong is completely omitting any attempt at usage from the question you are asking. We don't care if you are wrong, but only care that you actually tried. Seems to me the `"localField"` in the `"orders"` collection is `"orderedItems.name"`. From where I stand, if you actually tried something then there is a specific question you could ask. But that's not the question you are asking here, and all I see is "please do it for me". Happy to help explaining the part you don't understand if you identify it.

Comment: I'm so sorry for taking your time... I tried, and wrote some statement with $lookup, but edited it cause thought it's stupid... I don't feel well physically, got head ache almost all the time. I' really trying, but you know... 

db.orders.aggregate([
{$project : { _id: 0, client : 1 , orderedItems : 1 }},
{$unwind: "$orderedItems"},
{$group: { _id: "$orderedItems.name", total:{$sum: "$orderedItems.qty"}}},
{$lookup:{from: "stock", localField: 'orderedItems.name', foreignField: "item", as: "a"}},
{$match: { "a": { $ne: [] } }}
]);

Comment: There is no "try" [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47337188/edit). You **NEED** to actually show us what you tried. You also need to pay attention to the pretty clear instruction in the comment that basically shows you what the very first step is. Questions asking "Gimmie the codes" are reason for closure here. Show some effort in actually solving it and you'll get somewhere.

Comment: Look at earlier revision of my post

Answer (score 0):

How would you like something like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$orderedItems" // flatten the "orderedItems" array
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$orderedItems.name", // group by orderItems.name
        "total": {
            $sum: "$orderedItems.qty" // calculate total quantity
        },
        "users": {
            $addToSet: "$client" // create an array of clients who have ordered each item
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: { // retrieve the stock information
       from: "stock",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "item",
       as: "stock"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$stock" // flatten the result array - should always return only one document, given your data model
}, {
    $addFields: { // add a new field...
        "difference": { // ...called "difference"...
            $subtract: [ "$stock.qty", "$total" ] // ...in which we store the difference between the stock qty and the ordered qty
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: { // only return documents...
        "difference": { // ...where the value for "difference"...
            $lt: 0 // ...is less than zero
        }
    }
}])
```